# How to justify $\phi(n) \ge \sqrt{n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, totient-function

If $\phi(n)$ is the Euler-totient function, how can I show that
$\phi(n) \ge \sqrt{n}$?

Comment: $\varphi(2)=1<\sqrt2$.

Comment: I'm sure this question has been asked, and answered, here, but I'm not sure how to find it.

Comment: $\varphi(6) = 2 < \sqrt{6}$

Comment: See, for example, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301837/is-the-euler-phi-function-bounded-below --- especially Brian's answer.

Comment: @Gerry, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301837/is-the-euler-phi-function-bounded-below/301856#301856

Comment: It's true for $ n > \frac{81}{4} = 20.25,$ or $ n \geq 21.$

Comment: Hints: $\phi(n\cdot m)=\phi(n)\cdot\phi(m)$ if $n$ and $m$ are coprime, and $\phi(p^k) = p^{k-1}\cdot(p-1)$ for any prime number $p$

Answer (score 9):

Hint: both $\phi(n)$ and $\sqrt{n}$ are multiplicative, so it suffices to consider prime powers.