# euler function property $\varphi(n)\geq\sqrt{n}$

Tags: number-theory

How to prove that $\varphi(n)\geq \sqrt{n}$  for every positive integer $n$ distinct of $2$ and $6$.

Comment: Hint: you only have to prove this for powers of primes (think about why).

Comment: @Wojowu The case $n \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$ makes it a little harder.

Comment: From the duplicate's answer: Show that if $n$ is odd or a multiple of $4$, then $\varphi(n)\ge\sqrt n$; for this you’ll use the prime factorization of $n$ and the multiplicativity of $\varphi$. Then handle the case $n=2m$ with $m$ odd by using the multiplicativity of $\varphi$ to write $\varphi(n)=\varphi(2)\varphi(m)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer That's true, I didn't think about all the details of the proof, so I've missed that.

Comment: @DietrichBurde It seems to me the "duplicate" proved only that $\varphi(n)\geq \sqrt{n}$ when $n\not\equiv 2 \pmod 4$ and $\varphi(n)\geq \sqrt{n}/\sqrt2$ when $n\equiv 2 \pmod 4$.

Comment: @DavidK [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308686/how-to-justify-phin-ge-sqrtn) is the exact duplicate, if you want. But you will see that the idea goes back to Brian's answer above.

Comment: @DietrichBurde OK, the exact duplicate definitely qualifies as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have:

$$ \frac{\phi(n)}{n}=\prod_{p\mid n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\geq \prod_{p\leq n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)=\frac{1}{\sum_{m\in A_n}\frac{1}{m}}$$
where $A_n$ is the set of $n$-smooth numbers, i.e. the set of numbers having all their prime divisors $\leq b$. You just have to prove that:
$$ \sum_{m\in A_n}\frac{1}{m}\leq \sqrt{n}.$$
A good idea is to consider that:
$$ \sum_{m\in A_n}\frac{1}{m} = 1 +\sum_{p\leq n}\frac{1}{p}+\sum_{\substack{m\in A_n\\ \Omega(m)\geq 2}}\frac{1}{m} \leq \sum_{p\leq n}\frac{1}{p}+\left(\sum_{m\in A_n}\frac{1}{m}\right)^2$$
then it is enough to (roughly) estimate $\sum_{p\leq n}\frac{1}{p}$.