# $n$th prime bounded from above?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p_n$ be the $n$th prime, $p_n\#\equiv\prod_{k=1}^{n}p_k$ ([primorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Primorial.html)), and $\sigma(n)=\sum_{d|n}^{}d$ ([divisor function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisorFunction.html)).

Does $\text{exp}\bigg(\dfrac{\pi^2}{6 e^{\gamma}}\dfrac{\sigma(p_n\#)}{p_n\#}\bigg)$ bound $p_n$ from above?

(Note: From Daniel Fischer's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803250/asymptotic-divisor-function-primorials).)

[image]

## Update

... and from below by $\log(p_n\#)$?

[image]

Comment: Is the constant $\frac{\pi^2}{6e^{\gamma}}$ experimental? (just asking). Also, is $\gamma$ supposed to be the [Euler-Mascheroni](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) constant?

Comment: No - it is from Daniel Fischer's answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803250/asymptotic-divisor-function-primorials). And yes to the second :)

Comment: Since $\sigma$ is multiplicative, $\sigma(p_n\#)/p_n\#$ is just an obscure way of writing $$\prod_{i=1}^n \left(1 + \frac{1}{p_i} \right) $$