# Mathematical conjectures believed to be false

Tags: conjectures

I just came about the [Firoozbakht's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firoozbakht%27s_conjecture), and read that it is believed to be wrong, as it would contradict some heuristic methods. However, the conjecture is numerically verified for $p_n<10^{18}$.

Are there other examples of mathematical conjectures, that are believed to be false, however no counterexample has been found (even there was some effort to do it)?

Comment: should say $p_n < 10^{18}$

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630902/is-there-a-good-preferably-comprehensive-list-of-which-conjectures-imply-the-r/630970#630970

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11978/heuristically-false-conjectures

Comment: Thanks for the MO link, very interesting discussion. FLT for n=3 is wrong according to heuristics -  Wonderful :) But that tells something about the power of heuristic methods i guess.

Answer (score 2):

A lovely conjecture of Geoffrey Shephard states that for any convex 3-dimensional polytope there is a spanning tree T such that if one cuts along the edges of T then one can unfold the surface of the polytope to obtain a plane polygon where none of the faces of the polytope overlap.

I don't know if most people believe this to be false but for no good reason other than that I would like it to be true, I believe it to be true. It is known  that if one takes a "random" polytope that in a precise sense that random unfoldings do overlap. (See C. Schevon and J. O'Rourke. A conjecture on random unfoldings. Technical Report JHU-87/20, Johns Hopkins Univ., Baltimore, MD, July 1987.) nearly always as the number of vertices of the polyhedron increases.

On the other hand a student of Ziegler (Schlickenrieder, Wolfram. "Nets of polyhedra." Master's Thesis, Technische Universität Berlin (1997) showed that for a large number of choices of picking an "appealing" spanning tree to cut along in the hope of getting a non-overlapping unfolding, one could find a polytope where this appealing choice of tree did not work. So, it appears that for each polytope one needs to find "a needle in a haystack" tree T to get an unfolding that avoids overlaps.

If this conjecture were resolved positively it would appear that it would require some new insight into the nature of convex polytopes.