# Analog of Cramer's conjecture for primes in a residue class

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures, prime-gaps

Let $q$ and $r$ be fixed coprime positive integers, 
$$
1 \le r < q, \qquad \gcd(q,r)=1.
$$
Suppose that two prime numbers $p$ and $p'$, with $p<p'$, satisfy
$$
p \equiv p' \equiv r \ ({\rm mod}\ q),  \tag{1}
$$
and *no other primes* between $p$ and $p'$ satisfy $(1)$.
Then we have the following

**Naive generalization of [Cramer's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer's_conjecture) to primes in residue class $r$ mod $q$:**
$$
p'-p ~<~ \varphi(q)\,(\ln p')^2.   \tag{2}
$$

([PrimePuzzles Conjecture 77](http://www.primepuzzles.net/conjectures/conj_077.htm), A. Kourbatov, 2016). 
See [arXiv:1610.03340, "On the distribution of maximal gaps between primes in residue classes"](http://arxiv.org/abs/1610.03340) for further details, including the motivation for the $\varphi(q)$ constant.
Here, as usual, $\varphi(q)$ denotes [Euler's totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function).

**Note:** In the inequality $(2)$ we take the logarithm of the prime $p'$ *at the larger end* of the "gap".
Very few counterexamples to $(2)$ are known; see [Appendix 7.4 in arXiv:1610.03340](http://arxiv.org/abs/1610.03340). Definitely no counterexamples for $q=2, \ p<2^{64}$; also none for $1\le r < q \le 1000$, $ \ p<10^{10}$.

This conjecture (mostly in a less-naive "*almost always*" form) is mentioned in the following OEIS sequences listing *maximal (record) gaps between primes of the form* $p=qk+r$, $ \ \gcd(q,r)=1$:
[A084162](http://oeis.org/A084162),
[A268799](http://oeis.org/A268799),
[A268925](http://oeis.org/A268925),
[A268928](http://oeis.org/A268928),
[A268984](http://oeis.org/A268984),
[A269234](http://oeis.org/A269234),
[A269238](http://oeis.org/A269238),
[A269261](http://oeis.org/A269261),
[A269420](http://oeis.org/A269420),
[A269424](http://oeis.org/A269424),
[A269513](http://oeis.org/A269513),
[A269519](http://oeis.org/A269519).

**Question 1:** *Find a counterexample to conjecture* $(2)$.

**Question 2:** *Find a counterexample to $(2)$, with prime $q$ and prime $r$.*

**Question 3:** *Find a counterexample to $(2)$, with* 
$$
{p'-p \over \varphi(q)(\ln p')^2} > 1.1 \tag{3}
$$
([A.Granville predicts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer's_conjecture#Heuristic_justification) that such counterexamples exist even for $q=2$, with the above ratio greater than $1.12$ -- more precisely, Granville expects that the ratio should exceed or come close to $2e^{-\gamma}$).

**Question 4:** *Find a counterexample to $(2)$, with the additional condition
$p'-p>q^2$.*

**Hint:** Counterexamples are *very rare*. To find one, you will likely need to write a program and run it long enough. Good luck!

Comment: I do expect a counterexample. I only think that such counterexamples are very rare. Thank you!

Comment: No you don't except someone will find a counter-example if you already made some programs. That's why you need to make it clear...

Comment: Is that $\log \log p' $ or $(\log p')^2 $?

Comment: That's $(\log p')^2$.

Comment: Did you try discussing the random models underlying those things ? (in particular what is [Maier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_conjecture#Heuristic_justification)'s heuristic under which $\log^2(p)$ should be replaced by $\log^{2+\epsilon}(p)$)

Comment: I do not think Maier ever suggested replacing $\log^2p$ by $\log^{2+\epsilon}p$. It was [Adleman and McCurley](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-58691-1_70) who suggested $\log^{2+\epsilon}p$; whereas [Maier and Pomerance](https://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/paper75.pdf) (1990) just cautiously said that "we are a long way from proving these statements" -  i.e. statements like $G(x)\sim\log^2x$ or $\limsup(G(x)/\log^2x)=1$.

Comment: [Maier's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maier%27s_theorem) just tells us that, basically, *average* prime gaps near $x$, over relatively short intervals $[x,x+\log^\lambda x]$ infinitely often deviate up and down from the expected $\sim\log x$ and the deviation is so large that the limit of $$\frac{\pi(x+(\log x)^\lambda)-\pi(x)}{(\log x)^{\lambda-1}}$$ does not exist as $x\to\infty$. Based on this, Granville heuristically argues that *maximal* prime gaps near $x$ will also deviate from the expected $\sim\log^2 x$.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two counterexamples.

(A) Take $q=1605$, $r=341$, and consider the primes $p=3415781$ and $p'=3624431$.

It is not difficult to check that 
$$
      p \equiv p' \equiv r \ ({\rm mod} \ q),  \tag{1}
$$
and between $p$ and $p'$ there are no other primes satisfying $(1)$.
We have $\varphi(1605)=848$,
and the exceptionally large gap is
$$ 3624431 - 3415781 = 208650 > \varphi(q) \cdot (\log3624431)^2 = 193434.64\ldots
$$
(This only answers question 1.)

(B) Take $q=18692$, $r=11567$, and consider the primes 
$p=190071823$ and $p'=193978451. \ $
We check that $(1)$ holds for $p$ and $p'$ -- and for no other primes between $p$ and $p'$. We have $\varphi(18692)=9344$; our exceptionally large gap is
$$
3906628 = 193978451 - 190071823 > \varphi(q) \cdot (\log193978451)^2 = 
3402811.2255\ldots
$$
(This answers questions 1 and 3.)

As of December 2019, questions 2 and 4 are still open.