# Upper bounds for the $n$-th record gap between primes in a residue class

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures, prime-gaps

(Following [question 2269073](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2269073/). See also [respective lower bounds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453668/).)

Let $q$ and $r$ be coprime integers, $1\le r < q$, and consider the arithmetic progression
$$
r, \ r+q, \ r+2q, \ r+3q, \ldots \tag{P}
$$

Dirichlet proved that there are infinitely many primes in progression (P).

Let $R(n,q,r)$ be the $n$th record gap between primes in progression (P).
For example, with $q=6$ and $r=1$, we have $R(n,6,1)=\mbox{A268925}(n)$; see
http://oeis.org/A268925.

**Conjecture** (see [arXiv:1709.05508](https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.05508)): Almost all record gaps satisfy
$$
R(n,q,r) < \varphi(q) n^2 + (n+2)q\log^2 q. \tag{1}
$$

**Question 1:**
Find a counterexample to inequality $(1)$.
(You will likely need to write a program and run it long enough. No counterexamples exist for $r<q\le2000$ and $n\le14$.)

For comparison, here is a tighter conjectural bound (also for *almost all* record gaps): 
$$
R(n,q,r) < \varphi(q) n^2 + (n+2)\varphi(q)\log^2 q. \tag{2}
$$
Here
$\varphi(q)$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

A few counterexamples to $(2)$ are known; e.g. for $q=20$, $r=17$.

**Question 2:**
Find more counterexamples to inequality $(2)$.

Comment: The upper bound (1) together with the lower bound of [question 3453668](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453668/) constitute [Conjecture 84 at Primepuzzles.net](https://www.primepuzzles.net/conjectures/conj_084.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Take $q=23$ and $r=4$. The record gaps between primes $p\equiv 4$ (mod $23$) are
$$ 138 = 211 - 73,$$
$$322 = 809 - 487, $$
$$1150 = 4259 - 3109, $$
$$1380 = 144973 -143593, $$
$$2070 = 459337 - 457267 \ldots $$

The 5th record gap occurring between primes 457267 and 459337  in residue class 4 (mod 23) is
$$
2070 = 459337-457267 > 22\cdot5^2 + (5+2)\cdot22\cdot(\log23)^2 \approx2064.02. 
$$
This is a counterexample to inequality $(2)$ for $n=5$. (This only answers question 2.)