# Lower bound for the $n$-th record gap between primes in an arithmetic progression

Tags: number-theory, conjectures, prime-gaps

(This is a natural counterpart to [question 3132001](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3132001/) which deals with *upper bounds*.)

Let $q$ and $r$ be coprime integers, $1\le r < q$, and consider the arithmetic progression
$$
r, \ r+q, \ r+2q, \ r+3q, \ldots \tag{P}
$$

Dirichlet proved that there are infinitely many primes in progression (P) when $\gcd(q,r)=1$. This is *Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions*.

Let $R(n,q,r)$ be the $n$th record gap between primes in progression (P).
For example, with $q=6$ and $r=5$, we have $R(n,6,5)=\mbox{A268928}(n)$; see
http://oeis.org/A268928.

**Conjecture**: Almost all record gaps $R(n,q,r)$ satisfy
$$
R(n,q,r) > {1\over6} \varphi(q) n^2. \tag{L}
$$
Here
$\varphi(q)$ is [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

**Question:**
Find counterexamples to inequality (L).
(Please find as many as you can. You will likely need to write a program and run it long enough.)

Comment: This lower bound, as well as the upper bound of [question 3132001](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3132001/), constitute [Conjecture 84 at Primepuzzles.net](https://www.primepuzzles.net/conjectures/conj_084.htm)

Comment: There are no counterexamples to lower bound (L) for $1\le r<q\le2000$ and $n<15$.