# What are amazing results concerning Euler totient function?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, education, math-history, totient-function

What are important or amazing results involving the Euler totient function? I am aware of Euler's theorem but I am looking for results like the one Gauss proved:
$$\sum_{d\mid n}\phi(n)=n.$$
This is for first year undergraduate students who need motivating.

Comment: There's no shortage here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Other_formulae

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630902/is-there-a-good-preferably-comprehensive-list-of-which-conjectures-imply-the-r/630970#630970

Answer (score 4):

If $(x,y)=1$ then $x^{\phi(y)}+y^{\phi(x)}-1$ is divisible by $xy$.

Answer (score 2):

The [Nikolas criterion](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.3613.pdf) says that the Riemann hypothesis is true if and only if 
$$
\frac{N_k}{\phi(N_k)}>e^{\gamma}\log(\log(N_k))
$$
is true for all $k\ge k_0$ for some $k_0$, where $N_k=p_1\cdots p_k$ is the primorial. If you need "motivating" for number theory, this is a good start. Otherwise, it appears at many other places besides algebra and number theory, e.g., also in cryptography.

Answer (score 2):

The best elementary equivalent to the Riemann Hypothesis uses the totient.

In 1903, Landau showed
$$  \limsup \frac{n}{\phi(n) \log \log n} = e^\gamma $$
where $\gamma = 0.5772156649...$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant, and $e^\gamma \approx 1.78107241799$.

Rosser and Schoenfeld showed that, for $n \geq 3,$
$$   \frac{n}{\phi(n) \log \log n} < e^\gamma +  \frac{5}{2 (\log \log n)^2}   $$

and asked whether there were infinitely many $n$ such that $   \frac{n}{\phi(n) \log \log n} > e^\gamma  \; ? $

Nicolas showed that this was true, and his method gave an equivalent condition to RH. If RH is true, then $   \frac{n}{\phi(n) \log \log n} > e^\gamma  \;  $ is true whenever $n$ is a primorial number, the product of consecutive primes beginning with $2.$ If RH is false, the inequality in question is true for infinitely many primorials and false for infinitely many primorials.

This gives one of the very few equivalents to RH than can be experimented with by beginners. See my computer output at [Is there a good (preferably comprehensive) list of which conjectures imply the Riemann Hypothesis?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630902/is-there-a-good-preferably-comprehensive-list-of-which-conjectures-imply-the-r/630970#630970)

```
 Mon Jun 11 12:07:46 PDT 2018
    p      P / phi(P)         log P               log log P       P/( phi(P) e^g loglogP)
    2                   2  0.6931471805599453 -0.3665129205816643   -3.06379094454131
    3                   3   1.791759469228055  0.5831980807826592   2.888175572256308
    5                3.75   3.401197381662155   1.224127540701542   1.719978509896452
    7               4.375   5.347107530717468   1.676555766240811   1.465137808160487
   11              4.8125   7.745002803515839   2.047047835846279   1.319961222866451
   13   5.213541666666667   10.30995216097738   2.333109657957713   1.254631303651586
   17   5.539388020833334   13.14316550503359   2.575901890058003   1.207399221788066
   19   5.847131799768519   16.08760448420003   2.778049067645523   1.181738522506715
   23   6.112910517939816   19.22309870012918    2.95611261323859   1.161035464998139
   29   6.331228750723381   22.59039453011566   3.117524795139961   1.140240626240416
   31   6.542269709080827    26.0243817346008    3.25903385762329   1.127088435620055
   37   6.723999423221962   29.63529964724503   3.388966206450537   1.113983738311179
   41   6.892099408802511   33.34887171394934   3.507023940123642   1.103395540159158
   43   7.056197013773999    37.1100718296429   3.613888410657884   1.096262053809405
   47   7.209592601029955   40.96021943135295   3.712601337927668   1.090312093882832
   53   7.348238612588224   44.93051134490508   3.805117103941078    1.08426052178084
   59   7.474932381770779    49.0080487888108   3.891984545617405    1.07833718905661
   61   7.599514588133625   53.11892265298411   3.972533223580432   1.074080264626053
   67   7.714658748559892   57.32361527237508   4.048712672715189   1.069838407170301
   71   7.824868159253605   61.58629514941639   4.120439364446186   1.066232517238055
   73   7.933546883687683   65.87675459056479   4.187785641657706   1.063656432618303
   79   8.035259023222141   70.24620244303181   4.252006249002245   1.061022048725825
   83   8.133249986919971    74.6650430508284   4.313012018095531   1.058770603518944
   89    8.22567328222588   79.15367942056054   4.371391271924509   1.056501691508914
   97   8.311357378915734   83.72839039906393   4.427578112325172   1.053960043917184
  101   8.394470952704891   88.34351091590518   4.481232748596946   1.051754191389813
  103   8.476769687535331   92.97823990413482   4.532365486250344   1.050083614290286
  107   8.556739212889438   97.65106873859673   4.581400601846481   1.048644900766041
  109   8.635968279675451   102.3424166208259   4.628324216747023   1.047624596580641
  113   8.713075139315411   107.0698044395382   4.673480999695532    1.04676549842092
  127   8.782226529309977   111.9139915259968   4.717730643480057   1.045177171896372
  131   8.849782117996977    116.789188849198   4.760370504887452   1.043783061120183
  137    8.91485404533519   121.7091697750261   4.801634344525809   1.042422014929592
  139   8.979454436968053   126.6436437081568   4.841377187333173   1.041356551208377
  149   9.040126426407026   131.6475900141022   4.880128579767183   1.040067824401415
  151   9.100393935916406   136.6648698509172   4.917531723511503   1.039038031029536
  157   9.158729794479973   141.7211156562655   4.953861152223309   1.038029840266595
  163   9.215265163581702   146.8148658570722   4.989172377109704   1.037045351133325
  167   9.270778809145447    151.932859669489   5.023438710561754   1.036176010570164
  173   9.324678685942805   157.0861512639868    5.05679438901429   1.035325717576812
  179    9.37706452125709   162.2735370698275   5.089283411749193   1.034495699597304
  181   9.429159324152963   167.4720341010934   5.120816376735163   1.033837289825305
  191    9.47878647849061     172.72430752914    5.15169672527225   1.033048885613705
  193   9.528155158066083   177.9869977180449   5.181710501096219    1.03241450352531
  197   9.576768194586828   183.2702014467829   5.210961574509532   1.031857028285001
  199   9.625135710721105   188.5635062715074   5.239434853446014   1.031432564116454
  211   9.670969690295967   193.9153644049834   5.267421797917956   1.030837828491188
  223   9.714532616828832   199.3225361764435   5.294924297476561   1.030102822951811
  227   9.757517274425419   204.7474861939249   5.321777445216663   1.029440006877103
  229   9.800313402822022   210.1812081974792   5.347970054815063   1.028891120472213
  233     9.8425561330066   215.6322466510449   5.373574394877919   1.028402340291779
  239   9.883911410876376   221.1087102029764   5.398654481944868   1.027925720184415
  241    9.92509437508836   226.5935071364671   5.423157694769739   1.027544961042268
  251   9.964794752588713   232.1189600755988   5.447249999196909    1.02709229730082
  257   10.00371973209101   237.6680361604941   5.470874893975703   1.026651755594182
  263   10.04190186847304   243.2401901926718   5.494049392165235   1.026223216185692
  269   10.07937165156436   248.8349015722737   5.516789630658082   1.025806525361315
  271   10.11670265768126   254.4370203931534   5.539053341292237   1.025467403833489
  277   10.15335737745547   260.0610378993407   5.560916364614751   1.025136581067758
  281   10.18961936808924   265.6993925686745   5.582365566608373   1.024844818902675
  283   10.22575277010374   271.3448394663177   5.603390482330846   1.024619984542941
  293   10.26077247137122   277.0250120753348    5.62410779841172   1.024341676809461
    p      P / phi(P)         log P               log log P       P/( phi(P) e^g loglogP)
Mon Jun 11 12:07:46 PDT 2018
```