# Why Euler's Totient function is important?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, totient-function

First for it's importance in the field of abstract algebra:

- This function returns the cardinality (order) of the group $U(n)$ closed under modular multiplication.
- This function also returns the upper bound for the order of an arbitrary element in the $U(n)$.

And after that it's computational importance in modular arithmetic:

- Since residue exponention is not well-defined, reducing the exponent modulo $\varphi(m)$ is our only way out for simplyfing modular exponents due to the Euler-Totient theorem.
- With the same way above, if exponent of the element is relatively prime with the $\varphi(m)$, we can compute modular inverse of the exponent and with the help of it we can calculate modular roots. It is essential to RSA.

Are my points true? What i can add to this list?

Comment: For the second point, see [Carmichael's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function), which gives the best upper bound for multiplicative orders modulo $n$.

Comment: I'd say the core of modular arithmetic is the decomposition of the groups $\Bbb{Z}_n,\Bbb{Z}_n^\times$ and the ring $\Bbb{Z}_n$ in term of prime powers $p^k | n$ and $\varphi(n)$ encodes one of the main parameters of those things

Comment: This question overlaps https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2816053.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few things:

- You reduce many term polynomials, to just a few terms mod any value. (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3152587/largest-multiple-of-7-lower-than-some-78-digit-number/3152669#3152669) as applied to an integer, a less general form of polynomial).
- It shreds power towers down to size, with repeated use.
- It allows us to work in smaller numbers, rather than potentially
  trillion digit numbers.
- It allows us to pigeonhole principle coprime variable sets.
- You can generalize it to products of coprime arithmetic progressions. The product of the first 4 numbers in arithmetic progression 10k+9 have a product that is 1 mod 10 for example (193,401 for those wondering).
- Can be used to limit long division in finding the reptend length of fractions with coprime denominator in a given base.
- Cryptography ( forgot this)

  - etc.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason from abstract algebra:

If $n$ is a positive integer then every group of order $n$ is cyclic if and only if $\gcd(n,\varphi(n))=1$.

You can read about the history and proof of this result [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/allgrouporderncyclic.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwib8buJ457jAhVpn-AKHae5BH0QFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw0_AU2dqpKON-H017qWjVNs).