# Is the Nicolas function strictly increasing?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Denote by $p_j$ the $j$-th prime, and let $N_j =p_{1}p_{2}\cdots p_j$ be the $j$-th primorial number. Let $\varphi$ be the Euler totient function.
Define the Nicolas function $f(k):= \frac{N_k}{\varphi(N_k)\log \log N_k}$. My question: Is $f(k)$ strictly increasing ? Computational evidence up to $k=20$ seems to suggest so.

Comment: If that were proved it would also prove the Riemann Hypothesis.  See https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.3613

Comment: also by Nicolas but in English  https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.0729

Comment: I gave an explicit answer on this years ago. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630902/is-there-a-good-preferably-comprehensive-list-of-which-conjectures-imply-the-r/630970#630970

Comment: Apparently you wrote the reciprocal of the ratio that seems to increase