# Euler's constant's role in the Prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, euler-mascheroni-constant, research

I know that: $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\log p_n}\prod_{i=1}^k\frac{p_i}{p_i-1}=e^\gamma$$Where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime and $\gamma$ is Euler's constant. But why does this make the number $\gamma$ important in number theory (according to wikipedia)? I could say that $$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}H(k)-\frac{k}{\pi(k)}=\gamma$$Where $\pi(k)$ is the prime counting function (to prove this use the fact that $\pi(x)\sim\dfrac{x}{\log x}$ and then solve for $\log x$). But this doesn't make it useful.

Comment: I just want to point out that wikipedia says $e^\gamma$ is important in number theory, not $\gamma$

Comment: $e^\gamma$ is important in the random model for the primes, the one predicting things like the density of twin primes

Comment: there is the Nicolas equivalent to RH, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630902/is-there-a-good-preferably-comprehensive-list-of-which-conjectures-imply-the-r/630970#630970

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number $e^{\gamma}$ plays an important role in the theory of $y$-rough numbers , where the Buchstab-function can be used to estimate the number of $y$-rough numbers below $x$. And this function tends quickly to $e^{-\gamma}$

It is also useful to estimate the probability that a large random number $x$ is prime if it has no prime factor below $y$ , assuming $y$ itself is large , but $x$ much larger.

Neither the Euler number $e$ nor the Euler Mascheroni constant $\gamma$ are however important for all this, just the combined number.