# Sum versus product on Primes

Tags: limits, number-theory, exponential-function, analytic-number-theory, euler-mascheroni-constant

Disclaimer: I had a hard time choosing the title.

Hello MSE!

So in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4610432/eulers-constants-role-in-the-prime-numbers) I was wondering why $e^\gamma$ has importance in number theory while $\gamma$ and $e$ don't. But I have another question related to this. It is known that: $$e^\gamma=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left[\frac{1}{\ln p_k}\prod_{0<i\le k}\frac{p_i}{p_i-1}\right]$$But when we take the logarithm of both sides, and bring it into the limit (which is allowed since the logarithm is continuous), we get this limit for $\gamma$: $$\gamma=\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\left[-\ln\ln p_k+\sum_{0<i\le k}(\ln p_i-\ln(p_i-1))\right]$$What makes the limit for $e^\gamma$ more important than the limit for $\gamma$? I could tell that there is a product in the first limit while there is a sum in the second. Does this have to do with the numbers' importance in number theory?

Comment: The product: $$\prod_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{p_i^s}{p_i^s-1}$$ is $\zeta(s)$ when $\operatorname{Re}(s)>1.$ $\zeta$ has a pole at $s=1,$ and this product diverges at $s=1,$ and this theorem indicates how fast it diverges, namely: $$\prod_{i=1}^k \frac{p_i}{p_i-1}\sim e^{\gamma}\log p_k$$

Comment: In particular, if $N_k$ is the set of all natural numbers which only have primes $p_1,p_2,\cdots,p_k$ as prime divisors, then: $$\prod_{i=1}^k\frac{p_i}{p_i-1}=\sum_{n\in N_k}\frac1{n}$$

Comment: Just because $e^\gamma$ is important in number theory doesn't mean $e$ and $\gamma$ are not. The Fourier and Laplace transforms both involve $e$, and $\gamma$ appears in many equations in number theory.