# Different approach to $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \phi(n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, totient-function

This [old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692850/) recently popped up, and I thought about how I would answer it. My approach was nothing like the approaches in the given answers, which makes me wonder, **Is my approach invalid in some way?**

**Edited to account for objection raised in answer by Lukas Heger**

I reasoned that a product of a finite number of finite integers cannot become infinite.
Thus, if $n=\prod p_i^{a_i}$, then $n \rightarrow \infty$ only if one or more of $p_i \rightarrow \infty$, or if $i \rightarrow \infty$, or if one or more of $a_i \rightarrow \infty$ (or some combination of those). These conditions are sufficient to ensure that the product representing $n$ will have either an infinite number of prime factors (not necessarily distinct) or have prime factors that are arbitrarily large.

In any case it will be true that $\phi(n)=\prod (p_i-1)p_i^{a_i-1} \rightarrow \infty$ because necessarily one or more of $(p_i-1) \rightarrow \infty$ or $i \rightarrow \infty$ or one or more of $(a_i-1) \rightarrow \infty$

Am I right, or have I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is the following fact:

> **Lemma:** Let $f(n)$ be a positive multiplicative function. If $f(q)\to+\infty$ as prime power $q\to\infty$. Then $f(n)\to+\infty$ as positive integer $n\to+\infty$.

Suppose this lemma is true, we can set $f(n)=\varphi(n)$ so it follows from $\varphi(p^a)=p^a(1-1/p)>\frac12p^a$ that $\varphi(n)/n^{1-\delta}\to+\infty$ as $n\to+\infty$ for any fixed $\delta>0$.

*Proof.* By definition, for all $K>1$ there exists a prime power $q_0$ such that for all prime power $q>q_0$ there is $f(q)>K$.

Now, let $Q$ be all the prime divisors of a large positive integer $n$. Then we can partition set $Q$ into three subsets:

$$
Q_1=\{q|n:q>q_0\},\quad Q_2=\{q|n:q\le q_0,f(q)\ge1\},\quad Q_3=\{q|n:q\le q_0,f(q)<1\}.
$$

As a result, we have

$$
f(n)=\prod_{q_1\in Q_1}f(q_1)\prod_{q_2\in Q_2}f(q_2)\prod_{q_3\in Q_3}f(q_3)>K\underbrace{\prod_{q_3\in Q_3}f(q_3)}_{\text{bounded below}},
$$

in which the right most sum is bounded below because $Q_3$ is finite and $f(n)$ is positive. Thus, we see that $f(n)\to+\infty$ as $n\to+\infty$.