# Is there an integer $N>0$ such that $\varphi(n) = N$ has infinitely many solutions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $\varphi: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ be the totient function.

Is there an integer $N > 0$ such that there are infinitely many integers $n > 0$ such that
$$\varphi(n) = N?$$

Comment: Pardon me? Is not the totient function invertible?

Comment: [Hint:](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301837/is-the-euler-phi-function-bounded-below) $n > \varphi(n) > \sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}$ so $n<N-1$ and $n>2N^2$ cannot be solutions to $\varphi(n) = N$

Comment: @Winther: Useful, hitting the point. But where is the lower bound from?

Comment: Click on "Hint". It's a fairly simple proof, you can also find it in on the last page in this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.2068v3.pdf). btw much stronger bounds are found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Growth_of_the_function) and reads $\varphi(n) > \frac{n}{e^\gamma \log\log n + \frac{3}{\log\log n}}$

Comment: Thanks! I have just found a stronger lower bound that $\varphi(n) \geq \sqrt{n}.$ Please see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TotientFunction.html

Comment: Don't you mean the cototient function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. Let $M\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ and let $p$ be the smallest prime such that $p> M+1$. Let $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\varphi(n)=M$. Now, suppose $q\ge p$ is a prime factor of $n$. Then, write $n=q^k\cdot m$, fro some $k\ge 1$ and $q\nmid m$. Then, we get $$\varphi(n)=\varphi(q^k\cdot m)=\varphi(q^k)\varphi(m)\ge q-1\ge p-1>M,$$ 
contradiction. Thus, no prime divisor of $n$ can be greater than $M+1$.

Thus, the prime divisors of $n$ make up a finite set, say $\{p_1,\ldots,p_m\}$. Now, write $n=p_1^{e_1}\cdots p_m^{e_m}$, for $e_i>0$. Then,

$$\varphi(n)=\varphi(p_1^{e_1})\cdots\varphi(p_m^{e_m})=\prod_{i=1}^{m}p_i^{e_i-1}(p_i-1).$$
Now, note that for each prime $p_i$, we have $\varphi(n)\ge p_i^{e_i-1}(p_i-1)>M$ for a sufficiently large choice of $e_i$. Thus, for each $p_i$ there are only finitely many valid choices for the $e_i$, and it follows that the set of all $n$ s.t. $\varphi(n)=M$ is finite.

Comment: Why you first assume $\varphi(n) = M$ and later have $\varphi(n) > M$?

Comment: @Brian That yields a contradiction allowing us to say that no prime dividing $n$ is greater than $M+1$.

Comment: Ah yes, I just saw the "for suff. large ...".

Comment: Where is the first contradiction?

Answer (score 9):

No.

We use the fact that if $n = p_1^{e_1} \cdots p_k^{e_k}$, with the $p_i$ different primes and the $e_i$ positive, we have $\phi(n) = p_1^{e_1-1}(p_1-1) \cdots p_k^{e_k-1}(p_k-1)$.

Now consider an integer $N>0$ and suppose that $\phi(n) = N$. Then $n$ cannot be divisible by primes larger than $N+1$, since if $q > N+1$ divides $n$, we have $N+1 \leq q-1 \mid \phi(n) = N$, contradiction. The set of primes that may divide $n$, therefore, is finite. Let $p$ be such a prime. Then if $p^k \mid n$ we have $p^{k-1} \mid N$, which leaves a finite number of possibilities for $k$. Thus the number of primes that may divide $n$ is bounded and the exponent of each prime is bounded as well, thus there are at most finitely many $n$ for which $\phi(n) = N$.