# Lower Growth Rate of Euler Totient Function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Let $\phi(x)$ denote [Euler's Totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). What is the slowest growing function $f(x)$ such that $$\phi(x)=f(x)$$ occurs infinitely often for integers $x≥1$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your request for equality makes this impossible to answer in your exact words. However, from Rosser and Schoenfeld (1962) we get
$$ \varphi(n) \geq \frac{n}{e^\gamma \log \log n + \frac{2.50637}{\log \log n}} $$
where the constant $2.50637$ is chosen to give equality only at one number, the primorial $n= 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 \cdot 17 \cdot 19 \cdot 23 = 223092870. $

Rosser and Schoenfeld asked whether, if the inequality sign is reversed, it might be possible to erase the 2.50637 term for infinitely many numbers. Jean-Louis Nicolas (1983) showed that this was possible, and that the  question of saying "always" for primorials was equivalent to the Riemann Hypothesis. [ALL of the numbers Nicolas uses are primorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial). Primorials are the numbers with extremely low $\varphi,$ in exactly the same manner as [Ramanujan's Superior Highly Composite Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superior_highly_composite_number) are those with extremely large number of divisors. I gave the brief proof at [Is the Euler phi function bounded below?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301837/is-the-euler-phi-function-bounded-below/302592#302592)

In symbols, Nicolas showed that there are infinitely many numbers, primorials, such that
$$  \frac{n}{e^\gamma \log \log n + \frac{2.50637}{\log \log n}} < \varphi(n) < \frac{n}{e^\gamma \log \log n  } $$

See references 33-35 in the Wikipedia article; R+S can be downloaded. The paper of Nicolas, in French, is item 84 [HERE](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/publications.html) An interesting discussion in English [HERE](http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.3613)