# sequence and $\frac{\phi(n)}{n}$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $f$ be defined by $$f(n) = \frac{\phi(n)}{n}.$$ Then define a sequence $(n_k)$ by $$n_1 = 1, \mbox{and for } k \geq 2,$$
$$n_k = \ \mbox{smallest integer }n\ > n_{k-1} \ \mbox{with}\ f(n) > f(n_k)$$ for any $n < n_k$. Deduce a formula for $n_k$ and $f(n_k)$, with proof.

Sol. I try to calaulate some values of the $n_k$ as follows :
$$\begin{array}{c|ccccccccccccccccc}
n & 1 &2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17 \\ 
\hline
\phi(n) &1&1&2&2&4&2&6&4&6&4&10&4&12&6&8&8&16\\
\hline
f(n)&1&\frac{1}{2}&\frac{2}{3}&\frac{2}{4}&\frac{4}{5}&\frac{2}{6}&\frac{6}{7}&\frac{4}{8}&\frac{6}{9}&\frac{4}{10}&\frac{10}{11}&\frac{4}{12}&\frac{12}{13}&\frac{6}{14}&\frac{8}{15}&\frac{8}{16}&\frac{16}{17}
\end{array}$$

and so $n_1 = 1, n_2 = 2$,and $n_3 = 6$

To see what $n_k$ should be, it requires computations, and I still do not see potential formula.

Can anyone please suggest the formula, or a more effective way to analyse this problem ?

Comment: Try to get some more insight into how to compute $\phi(n)/n$: do you know how to do it easily knowing the prime factors of $n$?  Also, you know that $n_4 > 13$ so this helps you to guess that the sequence grows pretty quickly.  Does $1,2,6$ match any fast-growing sequence you are familiar with?

Comment: Yes, I think $$\phi(n)/n = \prod_{p|n} (1 - 1/p).$$ Oh, okay, so something connects to number of distinct prime dividing $n$, but might be more complicated.

Comment: That's correct, the value of $\phi(n)/n$ comes from the product of terms that are $<1$ coming from prime factors of $n$.  Now think about the following: what's the smallest possible value of $\phi(n)/n$ when $n$ has 1 prime factor (is prime)?  What's the smallest possible value with 2 prime factors?  What about 3?

Answer (score 2):

Erick is working this out with you, good. Eventually, you want two items, [PLANAT](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.3613) which is commentary on [NICOLAS](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/petitsphiDPP.pdf). The Nicolas paper appeared in the Journal of 
Number Theory, volume 17 (1983), pages 375-388 and has an English abstract.  Here we go, [NICOLAS 2012](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.0729.pdf) is an update, better estimates, in English.

In an earlier problem, I proved that Ramanujan's method, the same that gives the Superior Highly Composite numbers and the Colossally Abundant numbers, gives the same sequence that Erick is hinting at in comments. [Is the Euler phi function bounded below?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301837/is-the-euler-phi-function-bounded-below/302592#302592)