# Solutions to $\tau(n)=\varphi(n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've found seven $n$ for which $\tau(n),$ the number 0f divisors of $n,$ coincides with $\varphi(n),$ the "totient" function, number of integers from $1$ to $n$ and coprime to $n.$ Namely $1,3,8,10,18,24,30.$

Are there more? Or a relatively simple proof that this is all of them?

Thanks for any information.

Note: The answer of Wojowu proves the list complete. But it relies on a (to me) deep result for a lower bound on $\varphi(n)$ which holds for $n>1296.$ I'd still be interested in a simpler proof tht the list is complete, if possible.

Comment: A quick OEIS search resulted in this entry which contains a (sketch of a) proof. http://oeis.org/A020488

Comment: @Wojowu: you should promote your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This (finite) sequence exists on OEIS as [A020488](http://oeis.org/A020488). In the entry a proof is outlined and a link to an article (in Russian) where it was originally proven.

The idea of the proof is to show that $\tau(n)$ is significantly smaller than $\varphi(n)$. There is an easy upper bound
$$\tau(n)\leq 2\sqrt{n}.$$
Bounding $\varphi(n)$ from below is more tricky, you can see some arguments for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/301837/127263). One bound you can find there is
$$\varphi(n) \geq 2\left( \frac{n}{6} \right)^{2/3}.$$
Those two bounds together imply $\tau(n)<\phi(n)$ for $n>1296$.

Comment: $$  \varphi(n) \geq 2 \cdot   \left( \frac{n}{6} \right)^{2/3}.  $$ Method goes back to Ramanujan, although he did not include this easy application

Comment: @WillJagy Indeed, that's one of the bounds proven under the linked question. Perhaps I should include what the bound is in my answer.