# How to determine the order of an element of Special Linear Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups, self-learning, general-linear-group

Let,

$S=\begin{pmatrix}  0  &-1 \\ 1  & 0    \end{pmatrix}$
and
$T=\begin{pmatrix}  1  &1 \\ 0  & 1    \end{pmatrix}$ .

The matrices $S$ and $T$ generate $SL_2(\mathbb Z)$. The matrix $S$ has order $4 \: (S^2 = −I_2)$, while $T$ has infinite order.

Now consider we have an arbitrary element $\beta \in SL_2(\mathbb Z)$.

What is the process/ algorithm to determine/detect whether $\beta$ is an element of finite or infinite order?

Comment: It is not clear what the beginning of your post has to do with the last two sentences of your post, in which you actually ask the question you're interested in

Comment: [My post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3727661/81360) is related (but does not directly answer your question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A matrix with integer entries has finite order if and only if its [minimal polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)) can be expressed as a product of distinct [cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial).

In the $2 \times 2$ case, things are easy. One method would be to follow the following procedure. Begin with the matrix $\beta \in SL(\Bbb Z)$.

1. If $\beta$ is either $I$ or $-I$, then it has finite order. Otherwise, proceed
2. Find the characteristic polynomial of $\beta$, $p(x) = x^2 - \operatorname{tr}(\beta)x + 1$.  If we obtain one of the polynomials
   $$
   \Phi_3(x) = x^2 + x + 1, \quad \Phi_4(x) = x^2 + 1, \quad \Phi_6(x) = x^2 - x + 1,
   $$
   then $\beta$ has finite order (in particular, order $2,3,4,$ or $6$ respectively). Otherwise, $\beta$ has infinite order.

---

To summarize: a matrix $\beta \in SL(\Bbb Z)$ has finite order if and only if it is equal to $I$ or $-I$ or its trace satisfies $\operatorname{tr}(\beta) \in \{-1,0,1\}$.