# What is the largest (finite) order of an element of $GL_{10}(\mathbb{Q})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, field-theory

> What is the largest (finite) order of an element of $GL_{10}(\mathbb{Q})$?

The following is my guess: Let $A \in GL_{10}(\mathbb Q)$ is of finite order $n$ (say). Then $A^n=I$, or every eigenvalue of $A$ is an $n$-th root of $1$. Thus an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ has degree  $\leq\phi(n)$ over $\mathbb Q$. Equality holds only when $\lambda$ is primitive $n$-th root of $1$. OTOH $\lambda$ also satisfies the characteristic polynomial of $A$, which is of degree $10$. Thus if the characteristic polynomial is irreducible (e.g., $A$ is companion matrix of $X^{10}+X^9+\cdots+X+1$) then degree of $\lambda=10$, then we must have $\phi(n)\leq10$. The maximum $n$ such that $\phi(n)=10$ is $15$.
If I am doing some mistake please correct me. Thanks.

Comment: It’s not too bad a first guess, but $\phi(15)=8$, though… also, if the characteristic polynomial is irreducible, then $\lambda$ has degree $10$… why does this imply that $\phi(n) \leq 10$? Unless you restrict yourself to the case where there is some $\lambda$ such that $A$ and $\lambda$ have the same order… which isn’t always true. There is also this reliance on the irreducibility of the characteristic polynomial that doesn’t work too well either.

Comment: $x^8 + x^7 - x^5 - x^4 - x^3 + x + 1$ is a factor of $x^{30}-1$ and no lower $x^n-1$. So if you find a linear transformation with that as minimal polynomial... Somehow I imagine that's easier in $GL_8$. $x^{10} - x^9 + x^8 - x^7 + x^6 - x^5 + x^4 - x^3 + x^2 - x + 1$ is probably the best degree 10 polynomial to aim for, being a factor of $x^{22}-1$.

Comment: Hi @Arthur Just asking: How do you get those polynomials? Are there any systematic way of getting those?

Comment: I'm searching for "cyclotomic polynomials". Those are the polynomials that appear when you factor $x^n-1$ into irreducible factors. [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cyclotomic+polynomial+22) gives them out directly.

Comment: @Arthur: it’s not the highest $n$, actually. Not by far.

Comment: Interestingly, repeating this analysis for $GL_n(\Bbb Q)$ for $n = 1,2,\dots$ yields the sequence
$$
2,6,6,12,12,30,30,60,60,120,\dots
$$
which does not appear in the OEIS.

Comment: @Mindlack For some reason I didn't think about multiplying together different cyclotomic polynomials.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Briefly: the answer is $120$. One such matrix is
$$
A = 
\pmatrix{0&1\\& \ddots & \ddots \\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
\\
&&&&&&&\ddots & \ddots
\\
&&&&&&&&0&1
\\-1&-2 & -3 & -3 & -4 & -4 & -4 & -3 & -3 & -2}.
$$

---

Here is an approach to the problem.

The matrix $A$ will satisfy $A^n = I$ if and only if the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $x^n - 1$. Notably, $x^n - 1$ is a product of [cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) (which are irreducible over $\Bbb Q$), so the minimal polynomial of $A$ must be a product of these. Because $A$ has size $10$, its minimal polynomial has degree at most $10$.

Let $\Phi_n$ denote the $n$th cyclotomic polynomial. The degree of $\Phi_n$ is $\phi(n)$ (where $\phi$ denotes the Euler totient function). For a product $p = \Phi_{n_1} \cdots \Phi_{n_k}$ with $n_1,\dots,n_k$ distinct, the smallest $n$ for which $x^n - 1$ is divisible by $p$ will be $n = \mathrm{lcm}(n_1,\dots,n_k)$.

Putting all that together, we can frame the problem as follows:

> Maximize $\mathrm{lcm}(n_1,\dots,n_k)$ over all sets of distinct positive integers $n_1,\dots,n_k$ satisfying the constraint that $\phi(n_1) + \cdots + \phi(n_k) \leq 10$.

This maximal gcd will be equal to the largest possible finite order of an element of $GL_{10}(\Bbb Q)$.

Notably, there are [lower bounds](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/301837/81360) on $\phi$ that make it possible to obtain a solution by brute force. In particular, it is known that $\phi(n) \geq \sqrt{n/2}$. Thus, each $n_k$ must satisfy
$$
\sqrt{n_k/2} \leq \phi(n_k) \leq 10 \implies n_k \leq 200.
$$

---

After a systematic search I have found that the highest possible order is $120$. This maximum is attained with a matrix whose minimal polynomial is equal to
$$
\Phi_3\Phi_5\Phi_8 = (x^2 + x + 1)(x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1)(x^4 + 1).
$$
For instance, we can take $A$ to be the associated [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix).

Here's the Python code I used to compute this answer:

```
from math import gcd


def gcds(*args):
    if len(args) == 2:
        return gcd(*args)
    else:
        return gcds(gcd(*args[:2]),*args[2:])

def lcm(*args):
    if len(args) == 1:
        return args[0]
    if len(args) == 2:
        return args[0]*args[1]//gcd(*args)
    else:
        return lcm(lcm(*args[:2]),*args[2:])

def Ephi(n):
    s = 0
    for k in range(n):
        if gcd(k,n) == 1:
            s += 1
    return s

def get_list(deg, start = 1, M = 200):
    if deg == 0:
        return [[]]
    arr = []
    for k in range(start,M+1):
        phi = Ephi(k)
        if phi <= deg:
            new_deg = deg - phi
            new_M = 2*new_deg**2
            arr += [[k] + L for L in get_list(new_deg, start = k+1,  M = new_M)] # start=k allows repeats
    return arr

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    n = 10 # set value of n (in GL(n,Q)) here

    M = 2*n**2
    arr = get_list(n, M=M)
    print('    number of non-derogatory elements with finite order (up to iso): ' + str(len(arr)))
    m = 0
    for L in arr: 
        x = lcm(*L)
        if x > m:
            m = x
            mL = L
    print('    max order: %d'%m) #prints maximal order
    s = ''
    for k in mL:
        s += 'Phi_%d '%k
    # minimal polynomial of element with maximal order as product of 
    # cyclotomic polynomials
    print('minimal polynomial of maximal element: ' + s)
```

There are a few other candidates for the minimal polynomial. All together, the valid possibilies are
$$
\Phi_3\Phi_5\Phi_8,\\
\Phi_3\Phi_8\Phi_{10},\\
\Phi_5\Phi_6\Phi_8,\\
\Phi_6\Phi_8\Phi_{10}.
$$

---

Relevant paper: [Finite Groups of Matrices Whose Entries Are Integers](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2695329)

Comment: Is it $lcm(n_1,\ldots,n_k)$ instead of gcd of those?

Comment: @user371231 Yes! Sorry about that

Comment: a beautiful and thorough answer!