# Proving $\phi(x) = n$ for natural values of $n$ has finite solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

**Question**: Prove that for any given $n \in \mathbb N$, $\phi(x) = n$ has only finitely many solutions.

**My attempt:**

Let there be infinite solutions for

$$\phi(x) = n$$

so every natural number greater than $x$ has only $n$ primes before it. Thus, every number after the last prime is composite.

Now, let the finite set of primes be $p_1,p_2,...,p_n$.

Now, the number $p_1p_2...p_n + 1$ is relatively prime to all the finite primes, thus it is a new prime

This contradiction violates our assumption of a finite set of primes, so our assumption of infinite solutions is wrong.

Hence, $\phi(x) = n$ has only finite solutions.

**Issue**: I feel that the approach of $p_1p_2...p_n + 1$ is wrong and doesn't prove that the number itself is prime, but since it is of form $1 \text{ mod } p_i$ for $i \epsilon \text{ 1,2,...,n }$, thus it must be prime to all of them. Also, something about this proof feels off in terms of the assumptions. Any help is very appreciated!

***PS**: I know this is a duplicate but since I want to know what is wrong with my approach, I thought of sharing my method to get the explanation over the finite set of prime logic and the proof approach*

Comment: "every natural number greater than $x$ has only $n$ primes before it". What does this mean? $x$ is not fixed, it takes infinitely many values.

Comment: There's nothing wrong concluding that $p_1p_2..p_n + 1$ is a prime because you started from a false assumption, and from falseness everything follows (explosion principle). The important thing is that you reach a contradiction withou additional assumption

Comment: You haven't defined what the function $\phi(x)$ is. If you mean it to be the number of primes up to $x$, then $\pi(x)$ is the more common notation ($\phi$ is usually the Euler totient function).

Comment: We already know that there are infinitely many primes, so there's no need to go through Euclid's argument again. Since there are infinitely many primes, $p_{n+1}$ exists, and by definition $\pi(x) \ge n+1$ for all $x\ge p_{n+1}$. So there are at most $p_{n+1}-1$ solutions to $\pi(x) = n$. The proof doesn't need to be any longer than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: new answer due to change in OP question

Suppose $x$ has the following factorization:
$$x = \prod_{p|n}p^{k_p}$$
Using the Euler's product formula, we have
$$\phi(x) = \prod_{p|n}p^{k_p-1}(p-1)$$
Therefore
$$\frac{\phi^2(x)}{x} = \prod_{p|n}p^{k_p-2}(p-1)^2 \geq \prod_{p|n}\frac{(p-1)^2}{p}$$

since $k_p \geq 1$. Notice that $\dfrac{(p-1)^2}{p} > 1$ for $p >2$, therefore:
$$\frac{\phi^2(x)}{x} \geq \frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow \phi(x) \geq \sqrt{\frac{x}{2}}$$

If $\phi(x)=n$ then $n\geq\sqrt{\dfrac{x}{2}}$ therefore $x\leq2n^2$. Thus there can only be a finite number of solutions to $\phi(x) = n$

Comment: Did you assume $\phi $ is increasing?

Comment: @insomesense $\phi(x)$ in this context is "the number of primes not greater than $x$" so yes it is increasing.

Comment: $\phi$ is Euler's totient function.   $\phi(5)=4, \phi(6)=2.$  So it's not increasing.  It sounds like you may be thinking of the prime counting function.

Comment: @insomesense "so every natural number greater than x has only n primes before it". This is what OP said so I assume $\phi(x)$ is the prime counting function in this context.

Comment: Then it's terrible notation.   Especially considering the tag:  totient function.

Comment: @insomesense oh I didn't even notice the tag. Yeah I think OP understood the notation wrongly.

Comment: Sorry to all because what I had in mind was Euler's totient function. I forgot that the function counts the relatively prime numbers and not the primes before it. I am struggling.

Comment: @AyushMaurya please edit your question accordingly, I also modified my answer.

Comment: there is a bunch of stuff at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301837/is-the-euler-phi-function-bounded-below  including the Nicolas criterion for RH